# Components in delphi and C++ Builder?

Tags: delphi, components, c++builder

I have some components ( alpha controls ) I can install them to Delphi or C++ builder it works well. But when I Install Delphi version package I can't use components in C++ Builder forms, And when I install C++ Builder package I can't put components to Delphi form.

I want to create a new C++ builder project and add to it some Delphi forms then I must use the components in same time by C++ builder form and Delphi form.

some of components are available in both environments like VisionLab Components.
VisionLab comes with a Installer software that install VisionLab in both C++ and Delphi, But I must Install Alpha Controls from Source code.

Finally, I use RAD studio XE Architect. And Alpha controls version 7.26.

Comment: I have 2 Package one for Delphi XE and another one for CBuilder XE. I can use Component->Install Package to switch between Delphi and CBuilder bpl files. but when I try to mark both of delphi and CBuilder packages I see an Error message that say some components exists in previously selected package. I want to use this packages in a CBuilder application that contain some delphi forms. then I have to register components in delphi and CBuilder at same time. Or build a package for both CBuilder and Delphi.

Comment: I have the source code of this components ( Aplpha Controls ) Is it possible to Create a Package for both of delphi and CBuilder. as I said before There are some components that are usable in both CBuilder and delphi. I want to create package like them but **I don't know how to do that?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'll find that a majority of Delphi components will simply work for C++ if compiled with the correct flags. In the IDE this is done by selecting Options->Linker and choosing "Generate all C++ Builder Files". On the command line it is done by passing -JL to dcc32 when compiling the package. (dcc32 -JL mypackage.dpk) You then have to install the bpl file generated using this method into the IDE.

It is also possible to use components at runtime only by including them in a C++ project, but this is a less desirable user experience.

Comment: Hi Dear, Thanks for your attention. I do what you say but no Good answer, please read my comment on the top.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are using a component set that comes in distinct/separate packages for C++ and Delphi (with the same name) It is not possible to have both of them loaded into the IDE at the same time. I am aware of some component developers who choose to do this so that they can leverage each language's features more fully. This however yields the above problem.

Comment: Yes, You are right, but All of this components are in Delphi language and I want to load both c++ and delphi packages at same time in IDE, Is there any way to do this. I have all .pas files of components.

Comment: Thanks dear, before this I try to install both packages in same time but today I install only Delphi packages and compile it by Choosing "Generate all C++Builder files" and then I can put controls on the cBuilder and delphi forms.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have never used CBuilder so I am not 100% certain, but are you sure when you install Delphi components they are strictly for Delphi only? And the same if you install CBuilder components they will not show up in the Delphi IDE. Again I am not 100%, but I would of thought you would need to install the CBuilder packages for CBuilder, and the Delphi packages for Delphi?

Comment: Hi and Thanks. Your answer is "Yes" when I install them for delphi I Can't use Components in CBuilder and so on. I need use Components for CBuilder and Delphi at **same time**. Please read my comments on the top of page.